# AWS S3 Bucket Does Not Redirect to another S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created two S3 buckets on AWS, goop.dev and www.goop.dev  goop.dev bucket is used for static hosting and the endpoint shows the index.html file in the browser.  In the www.goop.dev I redirect the bucket to goop.dev bucket.  The endpoint in www.goop.dev times out in the browser with no display.

I can see the DNS information for goop.dev https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/goop.dev and is it fine.  This is not the same for www.goop.dev

I get this error "resource (goop.dev) is online but isn't responding to connection.

Comment: I believe you need to add a route53 record in order for the resolution to hit your bucket properly. This use to be much more hacky but it seems AWS finally got around to it, have you tried this tutorial (specifically step 3)? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html